# Remote access not showing enable option

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

Maybe a silly question.

I am following the instructions as dictated [here](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-access-windows-8/), but when I get my remote access tab, I only see the following (which seems to be missing that checkbox):

[image]

Comment: Windows 8 or 8.1? You need to have Pro version for *Remote Desktop*. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment:

As said in Microsoft's [website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compare), you need to have Windows 8.1 Pro to have *Remote Desktop*. All editions have *Remote Assistance* (as you do in your picture).

This applies to both Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.

---

I suggest using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) to replace Remote Desktop. It's free and allows other people to remotely connect to your computer or yourself to remotely access your computer. I find TeamViewer really helpful (BTW I'm just a regular user - not affiliated with TeamViewer)

Comment: The free version of [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/) also works in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop Option is totally different from Remote Access.
You simply cannot see this option because you don't have the Windows Professional edition installed.
Check this :
[Windows 8 versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compare)